# Alternative to Tajpi that types Esperanto characters?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I can't type any Esperanto letters on my keyboard that have the `^` sign after typing <kbd>^</kbd>. Here are my attempts: `^c ^g ^h ^j ^s ^u`. None works.

So I downloaded Tajpi, but it ignores my settings on how to respond to my keyboard input. Also, when I press <kbd>^</kbd> once, it types out `^^` so there's no way to type it like I'm used to.

I've searched for Windows Keyboard Layout Maker (something like that, I don't remember the name), but it's for Vista and it has a broken link on Microsoft's site.

I'm now looking for an input method/driver that will remap my keyboard input. When I press <kbd>^</kbd>, nothing should show until I:

1. Press again <kbd>^</kbd> to type `^^`
2. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to type `^`
3. Press any currently supported letter like <kbd>a</kbd> to type `â`
4. And most importantly press <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>u</kbd> to type `ĉ`, `ĝ`, `ĥ`, `ĵ`, `ŝ`, `ŭ`

Steps 1, 2 and 3 work regularly with my keyboard, but step 4 doesn't work at all. With Tajpi, none of the above works.

Is there a program that solves my problem?
If possible, I would love it if it could work with UTF-8 and Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

The Super User question [How to make ^ and ` non-dead-keys on Windows 7 with German keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout) is about the reverse situation. In an answer, [Tobias Plutat suggests](https://superuser.com/a/280032/151741) to use **The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator**, which allows you to

> assign or un-assign dead key behavior

The tool [can be downloaded from microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). According to its installation requirements, Windows 7 is supported (it doesn’t list Windows 7 on the download page you get redirected to, but the documentation on that page seems to be for the older version 1.0, not the current 1.4).

As I’m not using Windows, I couldn’t try it, but at least on GNU/Linux the behaviour you desire is the default one if <kbd>^</kbd> is set as **dead-key** (except for <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, which creates `û` instead of `ŭ`, which makes sense, I guess), so I assume it should be the same for Windows. At least the `â` is listed on Microsoft’s [Common Dead-Key Combinations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195156.aspx).

Comment: Is there another program?

Comment: "As I’m not using Windows" - ain't one of the requirements here that you use the software yourself? Anyway, I'd recommend the same, so +1

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Not a *requirement* (e.g., see ["Personal involvement in answers" in the answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/387/60), or the question [How important is personal experience?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/326/60)), but having personal experience is of course preferable.